# Display Woocommerce Additional tax classes on Product Page

Tags: php, wordpress

I've set two new additional tax classes

GST @ 5%
GST @ 12%

[additional tax classes settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auSzG.png)

and applied one of these to the product listing

[product listing settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcbAN.png)

How do I get it to display under the price on the frontend of the product page?

[product frontend display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAqAO.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you use php and html

Comment: How do I show it? is there any code or files to edits?

Answer (score 0):

all this custom field save in meta post data.
you can use this :

in this code , _video  is name of your meta.

Comment: Sorry, I'm complete new at this. Can you explain in more detail please?

Answer (score 0):

You Can do That for add custom field in woocommerce product (in Functions.php ) :

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );
function woo_add_custom_general_fields() {

  global $woocommerce, $post;

  echo '<div class="options_group">';
  echo '<h4 style="margin-right: 10px; color: #5573aa;">tax option</h4>';
  // Text Field
woocommerce_wp_text_input(
    array(
        'id'          => '_tax',
        'label'       => __( 'tax', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => 'Product tax',
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __( 'Enter tax here', 'woocommerce' )
    )
);
  echo '</div>';

}
```

And Then For Save This :

```
function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){

    // tax Field
    $woocommerce_text_field = $_POST['_tax'];
    if( !empty( $woocommerce_text_field ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_tax', esc_attr( $woocommerce_text_field ) );


}
```

Finally you Can Use this code to show tax field in your template :

```
echo get_post_meta($post_id, '_tax' , true);
```

Comment: Hi, where do I add this code?

function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){

    // tax Field
    $woocommerce_text_field = $_POST['_tax'];
    if( !empty( $woocommerce_text_field ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_tax', esc_attr( $woocommerce_text_field ) );


}

Comment: ok which template do I add the echo get_post_meta($post_id, '_tax' , true);

Comment: where you want to show the Tax Value? if you want for example show the tax value in the index or single , edit single.php or index.php and put this code where ever your want.

Comment: @jamore That's Ok ?